# I'm logged into two Google accounts, and every time I open Gmail, the wrong account is used

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-multi-login

Let's say my 2 Google accounts are called Primary and Secondary. I chose these names to reflect their function: I almost exclusively use "Primary". But I'm logged into both (intentionally). Every time I open Gmail, the Secondary account is used ("is active"). Every time I switch to "Primary" (which works), but when I close Gmail and open it again, it's Secondary again.

Is this because of the order in which I logged into the two accounts? Or why? And can I fix it?

**Note:** I don't have this problem in YouTube.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer [here](http://www.loudtechie.com/how-to-set-a-default-google-account-for-multiple-gmail-account-users/).

Summary of the fix:

1. Log out of Google (this logs you out of all your Google accounts)
2. Log in into your accounts in such an order that the first one is the one you want to be "default".

Comment: Does not seem to work on chrome browser on a chromebook with chrome OS. I wonder if the Chrome OS is holding onto the account information in a way that signing out of both Google and the chrome OS does not sign out the secondary account.

Comment: On chrome, you can clear all cookies for one website at settings > privacy and security > cookies and other site data > see all site data and permission > search for the site you want to reset and remove it. Then it should ask you the query at login time.

Comment: I tried this as well. Logged out of both accounts. Logged in ONLY to the account I want to use. Not logged into the other account at all. It still uses the wrong account.

Answer (score 5):

What I usually do to switch between my emails is by changing the `url`? You can see this `url` on your address bar

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/
```

see that `0` change it to `1`, to change it to your second gmail account.